# AssetManager.list - results too big for certain devices

Tags: android

I have a directory in my assets folder that has a large number of png files in it (600+). When I make a call to "assetManger.list()" on older devices, I get a "ReferenceTable overflow (max=512)" warning, and then a "Failed adding to JNI local ref table (has 512 entries)" error, which crashes the app essentially.

On newer devices this doesn't ever happen.

Is there a different way to list/loop over files in a directory on Android?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to scrap this approach and do something completely different. Looks like there is simply no other way to list files in an assets folder other than using the .list method. Oh well.